# or in namedQueries in Grails 2.3.8: AbstractMethodError

Tags: grails, grails-orm

After upgrading from Grails 2.2.4 to 2.3.8 I'm getting

> > java.lang.AbstractMethodError: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.or(Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Lorg/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/Criteria;

in a query

```
class Trip {
    TripParticipant driver, passenger

    static namedQueries = {
        byParticipant { UserAccount ua, name = null ->
            or {
                for( n in ( name ? [ name ] : [ 'driver', 'passenger' ] ) ) {
                    eq "${n}.account", ua
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}

class TripParticipant {
    UserAccount account

    boolean rated = false
}
```

any ideas?

TIA

UPDATE

http://www.file-upload.net/download-8906460/dependency-report.txt.html
 is the output of `dependency-report`

Comment: Can you also add concerned domain classes and how this query is called to just expand the context?

Comment: `UserAccount` is the spring-security oriented class, the named query is called inside a controller action. The whole setup is pretty simple

Comment: Just to be sure, a `clean-all` fixes a lot of weird stuff from time to time.

Comment: tried with clean and clean-all >> the exception is still the same

Comment: can it be, that the `or` criteria statement was deprecated in 2.3.8? I removed it, and it works!

Comment: Please post your `dependency-report`, this is probably a dependency conflict due to the version of hibernate plugin you are using

Comment: see the update please. btw `and` is also not working

Comment: I have a similar issue with my "polyglot persistence" app with the latest mongo and hibernate3 plugins (3.0.1 and 3.6.10.15, respectively). I see `[20-May-2014 17:56:51.535 CDT] ERROR - plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager [] Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [hibernate:3.6.10.15]: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/QueryAliasAwareSession
` Whenever I test-app in non-forked mode or run-war.

Comment: then we have either to wait for the updates of GORM-plugins or downgrade the mongo (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

when I downdraded mongo-db plugin from

> > compile ':mongodb:3.0.1'

to

> > compile ':mongodb:3.0.0'

it worked like charm again.

Comment: The original error message suggests that you are using the HibernateCriteriaBuilder.  Are you using both Hibernate and Mongo?

Comment: yes, i do. "polyglot persistance" or something ;). The namedQuery has nothing to do with mongo, it's a plain query against MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downgrade mongodb try and upgrade the version of `hibernate` you are using to the latest version to make sure the 2 project’s dependencies are in sync

Comment: I'm using `compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.13" compile ':mongodb:3.0.0'`. I tried to update hibernate to 3.6.10.14 as per http://grails.org/plugins/hibernate , but the version couldn't be resolved

Comment: shall I use the hibernate 4 plugin?

Comment: so, what would be you suggestion? shall I stay with hibernate3 or go for hib4? Shall I make any changes in `grails.project.dependency.resolution.repositories` to be able to resolve `compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.14"`?