# Best version of the mongodb gorm plugin for grails 2.2.x?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

Will the current MongoDB GORM plugin work on grails 2.2.x versions ?  Specifically grails 2.2.3. 
Just a note, upgrading to grails 2.3 is really not an easy option for this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with various combinations. 
I have found that it's the 1.3.3 version of mongodb that worked for my grails version 2.2.3.

additional notes:

I also had to use the 1.1.9 versions grails-datastore-core  and grails-datastore-simple
as the 1.1.8 versions were causing a class def not found for StatelessDatastore.

I use maven for my build so the final dependencies I added look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-datastore-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-datastore-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for the replies everyone.

Comment: Looks like you didn't upvote anyone's answer and you accepted yours :(

Comment: It was the first correct answer. You are allowed to choose your own answer if it's correct.

Comment: In my opinion +1's are better than "Thanks for the replies everyone." that nobody will read.

Answer (score 2):

After a few tests, the last version of the mongodb Grails plugin compatible with Grails 2.2.x (2.2.4 in my case) seems to be 1.3.3.

Trying to use the version after (2.0.0) gives the following:

`Plugin mongodb-2.0.0 requires version [2.3.2 > *] of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the latest one: 3.0.1

This version has support for mongodb 2.6

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, I meant the grails versions.

Comment: Yes, I think you can use the 3.0.1 MongoDB GORM plugin with 2.2.3 Grails version. In my past job, we were using the 2.0 plugin version with 2.2.3 grails version in production

Comment: Does it support as mongodb 2.4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

watch out!

mongo 3.0.1 uses updated version of gorm/hibernate libs, which are incompatible with the ones delivered with `hibernate:3.6.10.13` (the most recent version is 3.6.10.14, but when I try getting it, the dependency couldn't be resolved). That means, that the libs in the older versions of hibernate plugin can not be newer than that.

see [or in namedQueries in Grails 2.3.8: AbstractMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581133/or-in-namedqueries-in-grails-2-3-8-abstractmethoderror) for details.

I had to switch from 3.0.1 back to 3.0.0. If you want to upgrade you mongo java driver, you can do it via dependencies w/o upgrading the grails plugin. Heck! I even used aggregation in `mongodb:1.0.0.RC3` :)